# Parsing with beautifulsoup - not as expected

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse any airbnb calendars - but it isn't returning what I'm expecting...

Some code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

Driver = webdriver.Firefox()
Driver.get("https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/17394193?location=Whitby&check_in=2020-05-18&check_out=2020-05-21&source_impression_id=p3_1588098317_3ZR4OmXOPF8LDdm7&guests=1&adults=1")
url = Driver.current_url
PageSourceURL = Driver.page_source

Soup = BeautifulSoup(PageSourceURL, features='html.parser')
PageHTML = Soup.prettify()
print(PageHTML)
```

Output:

```
<html class="js-focus-visible" data-is-hyperloop="true" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
 <head>
  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
  </script>
  <script>
   window.sherlock_firstbyte = window.performance && window.performance.timing ? window.performance.timing.responseStart : Number(new Date());
  </script>
  <script>
   !function(){"use strict";var e=730,n="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";var t=/(?:^| )bev=(.*?)(?:;|$)/,o=!1;function a(){return window.bev=window.bev||function(){if(o||"undefined"==typeof document)return null;o=!0;var e=(document.cookie||"").match(t);return e&&2===e.length?decodeURIComponent(e[1]):null}(),window.bev}!function(){try{if(!a()){var t=function(){for(var e=[],t=15;t>=0;t--)e.push(n[Math.floor(Math.random()*n.length)]);var o=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3);return"".concat(o,"_").concat(e.join(""))}();o=t,r=document.location.hostname,c=".".concat(r.slice(r.indexOf("airbnb."))),(i=new Date).setDate(i.getDate()+e),document.cookie=["bev=".concat(encodeURIComponent(o)),"expires=".concat(i.toUTCString()),"path=/","domain=".concat(c),"secure"].join("; "),window.bev=t,function(e){var n=new XMLHttpRequest;n.open("POST","/tracking/events",!0),n.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");var t={event_name:"bev_created",event_data:{bev:e,page_uri:document.location.pathname,page_referrer:document.referrer}};n.send(JSON.stringify(t))}(t)}}catch(e){window.console&&console.error("Could not set bev cookie:",e)}var o,r,c,i}()}();
  </script>
  <script>
   (function() {
  var pgRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var diffStamp = Date.now().toString() + Math.random().toString().substring(2);
  pgRequest.open('GET', '/pg_pixel?r=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer || '') + '&diff=' + diffStamp, true);
  pgRequest.send();
})()
  </script>
  <script>
   // FID init code.
(function(a,b){function c(a){l.push(a),f()}function d(a,b){i||(i=b,j=a,k=new Date,f())}function e(){i&&(i=null,j=null,k=null)}function f(){0<=j&&j<k-n&&(l.forEach(function(a){a(j,i)}),l=[])}function g(c,e){function f(){d(c,e),h()}function g(){h()}function h(){b("pointerup",f,m),b("pointercancel",g,m)}a("pointerup",f,m),a("pointercancel",g,m)}function h(a){if(a.cancelable){var b=1e12<a.timeStamp,c=b?new Date:performance.now(),e=c-a.timeStamp;"pointerdown"===a.type?g(e,a):d(e,a)}}var i,j,k,l=[],m={passive:!0,capture:!0},n=new Date;(function(a){["click","mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"].forEach(function(b){a(b,h,m)})})(a),self.perfMetrics=self.perfMetrics||{},self.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=c,self.perfMetrics.clearFirstInputDelay=e})(addEventListener,removeEventListener);
// FCP init code.
(function(a){function b(){return!!document.body&&null!==document.createNodeIterator(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,function(a){return!!a&&/[^\s]/.test(a.nodeValue)&&"SCRIPT"!==a.parentNode.tagName&&"STYLE"!==a.parentNode.tagName&&0<a.parentNode.offsetHeight},!1).nextNode()}function c(){return null!==document.querySelector("input[placeholder]")}function d(){return b()||c()?void a(function(){var a=performance.now();f?f(a):g=a,performance.measure("TTFCP")}):void a(d)}function e(a){g?a(g):f=a}var f,g;a(d),self.perfMetrics=self.perfMetrics||{},self.perfMetrics.onFirstContentfulPaint=e})(requestAnimationFrame);    
// TTFMP Polyfill code.
(function(a){function b(){var c=document.getElementById("FMP-target");if(h=0,!c)e=a(b);else if(g===c)e=a(b);else if("IMG"===c.tagName&&!c.complete)e=a(b);else{var d=performance.now();g=c,f?f(d):h=d,performance.measure("TTFMP")}}function c(a){h?a(h):f=a}function d(){cancelAnimationFrame(e)}var e,f,g,h;e=a(b),self.perfMetrics=self.perfMetrics||{},self.perfMetrics.onFirstMeaningfulPaint=c,self.perfMetrics.startSearchingForFirstMeaningfulPaint=function(){g=document.getElementById("FMP-target"),b()},self.perfMetrics.stopSearchingForFirstMeaningfulPaint=d})(requestAnimationFrame);
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="en-GB" name="locale"/>
  <meta content="notranslate" name="google"/>
  <meta content="138566025676" property="fb:app_id"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" property="og:site_name"/>
  <meta content="en_GB" property="og:locale"/>
  <meta content="https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/skeleton" property="og:url"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:title"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:description"/>
  <meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
  <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/common-59f479fe1e596df7f1f7830bd5ea15bb.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/map_search-05b2e8d7a5602d7f9224bf29250fcd41.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/dls/dls-lite_cereal-d9f6fdb2a0dd4a18c37f8ee01de8ec3d.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/dls/dls-lite_o2-leftover-3644a5fa97a2e311cd1cd1dab8abaf5f.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <meta content="138566025676" property="fb:app_id"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" property="og:site_name"/>
  <meta content="en_GB" property="og:locale"/>
  <meta content="https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/skeleton" property="og:url"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:title"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:description"/>
  <meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
  <meta content="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logos/trips-og-1280x630-9de9c338cc3fd9b5663fb80be0cbe8c2.jpg" property="og:image"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logos/trips-og-200x200-a3be4fbbb3b6c5e758804438dea35adc.jpg" rel="image_src"/>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" id="csrf-param-meta-tag" name="csrf-param"/>
  <meta content="null" id="csrf-token-meta-tag" name="csrf-token"/>
  <title>
   Holiday Lets, Homes, Experiences &amp; Places - Airbnb
  </title>
  <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="" id="english-canonical-url"/>
  <meta content="on" name="twitter:widgets:csp"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/skeleton" rel="canonical"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="en" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.de/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="de" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.it/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="it" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.es/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="es-ES" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="fr" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.com.br/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="pt" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.dk/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="da" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="en-GB" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.ru/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="ru" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.pl/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="pl" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.co.kr/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="ko" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.cz/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="cs" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.hu/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="hu" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.at/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="de-AT" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.pt/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="pt-PT" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.gr/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="el" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.com.tr/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="tr" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.nl/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="nl" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.se/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="sv" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.com.tw/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="zh-TW" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.com.sg/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="en-SG" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.co.id/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="id" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.com.my/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="ms" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="en-AU" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.jp/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="ja" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.is/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="is" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.no/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="no" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://www.airbnb.ch/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="de-CH" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://fr.airbnb.ch/rooms/skeleton" hreflang="fr-CH" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="https://it.airbnb.ch/rooms/sk
None
```

Now what I want to be able to do is search through and find things like the following:

[image]

In the parsed data from beautifulsoup there are no div class elements etc.

I'm new to scraping - so am not sure if my expectations are in the wrong place, I've used the parser incorrectly or something else...

Hence **any** pointers will be much appreciated
Thanks
Rob

**UPDATE** Following the recommendation below to add a wait delay until the table is loaded, the amended 'Soup' is:

```
<html class="js-focus-visible" data-is-hyperloop="true" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
 <head>
  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
  </script>
  <script>
   window.sherlock_firstbyte = window.performance && window.performance.timing ? window.performance.timing.responseStart : Number(new Date());
  </script>
  <script>
   !function(){"use strict";var e=730,n="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";var t=/(?:^| )bev=(.*?)(?:;|$)/,o=!1;function a(){return window.bev=window.bev||function(){if(o||"undefined"==typeof document)return null;o=!0;var e=(document.cookie||"").match(t);return e&&2===e.length?decodeURIComponent(e[1]):null}(),window.bev}!function(){try{if(!a()){var t=function(){for(var e=[],t=15;t>=0;t--)e.push(n[Math.floor(Math.random()*n.length)]);var o=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3);return"".concat(o,"_").concat(e.join(""))}();o=t,r=document.location.hostname,c=".".concat(r.slice(r.indexOf("airbnb."))),(i=new Date).setDate(i.getDate()+e),document.cookie=["bev=".concat(encodeURIComponent(o)),"expires=".concat(i.toUTCString()),"path=/","domain=".concat(c),"secure"].join("; "),window.bev=t,function(e){var n=new XMLHttpRequest;n.open("POST","/tracking/events",!0),n.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");var t={event_name:"bev_created",event_data:{bev:e,page_uri:document.location.pathname,page_referrer:document.referrer}};n.send(JSON.stringify(t))}(t)}}catch(e){window.console&&console.error("Could not set bev cookie:",e)}var o,r,c,i}()}();
  </script>
  <script>
   (function() {
  var pgRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var diffStamp = Date.now().toString() + Math.random().toString().substring(2);
  pgRequest.open('GET', '/pg_pixel?r=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer || '') + '&diff=' + diffStamp, true);
  pgRequest.send();
})()
  </script>
  <script>
   // FID init code.
(function(a,b){function c(a){l.push(a),f()}function d(a,b){i||(i=b,j=a,k=new Date,f())}function e(){i&&(i=null,j=null,k=null)}function f(){0<=j&&j<k-n&&(l.forEach(function(a){a(j,i)}),l=[])}function g(c,e){function f(){d(c,e),h()}function g(){h()}function h(){b("pointerup",f,m),b("pointercancel",g,m)}a("pointerup",f,m),a("pointercancel",g,m)}function h(a){if(a.cancelable){var b=1e12<a.timeStamp,c=b?new Date:performance.now(),e=c-a.timeStamp;"pointerdown"===a.type?g(e,a):d(e,a)}}var i,j,k,l=[],m={passive:!0,capture:!0},n=new Date;(function(a){["click","mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"].forEach(function(b){a(b,h,m)})})(a),self.perfMetrics=self.perfMetrics||{},self.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=c,self.perfMetrics.clearFirstInputDelay=e})(addEventListener,removeEventListener);
// FCP init code.
(function(a){function b(){return!!document.body&&null!==document.createNodeIterator(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,function(a){return!!a&&/[^\s]/.test(a.nodeValue)&&"SCRIPT"!==a.parentNode.tagName&&"STYLE"!==a.parentNode.tagName&&0<a.parentNode.offsetHeight},!1).nextNode()}function c(){return null!==document.querySelector("input[placeholder]")}function d(){return b()||c()?void a(function(){var a=performance.now();f?f(a):g=a,performance.measure("TTFCP")}):void a(d)}function e(a){g?a(g):f=a}var f,g;a(d),self.perfMetrics=self.perfMetrics||{},self.perfMetrics.onFirstContentfulPaint=e})(requestAnimationFrame);    
// TTFMP Polyfill code.
(function(a){function b(){var c=document.getElementById("FMP-target");if(h=0,!c)e=a(b);else if(g===c)e=a(b);else if("IMG"===c.tagName&&!c.complete)e=a(b);else{var d=performance.now();g=c,f?f(d):h=d,performance.measure("TTFMP")}}function c(a){h?a(h):f=a}function d(){cancelAnimationFrame(e)}var e,f,g,h;e=a(b),self.perfMetrics=self.perfMetrics||{},self.perfMetrics.onFirstMeaningfulPaint=c,self.perfMetrics.startSearchingForFirstMeaningfulPaint=function(){g=document.getElementById("FMP-target"),b()},self.perfMetrics.stopSearchingForFirstMeaningfulPaint=d})(requestAnimationFrame);
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="en-GB" name="locale"/>
  <meta content="notranslate" name="google"/>
  <meta content="138566025676" property="fb:app_id"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" property="og:site_name"/>
  <meta content="en_GB" property="og:locale"/>
  <meta content="https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/17394193" property="og:url"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:title"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:description"/>
  <meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
  <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/common-59f479fe1e596df7f1f7830bd5ea15bb.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/map_search-05b2e8d7a5602d7f9224bf29250fcd41.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/dls/dls-lite_cereal-d9f6fdb2a0dd4a18c37f8ee01de8ec3d.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/dls/dls-lite_o2-leftover-3644a5fa97a2e311cd1cd1dab8abaf5f.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <meta content="138566025676" property="fb:app_id"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" property="og:site_name"/>
  <meta content="en_GB" property="og:locale"/>
  <meta content="https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/17394193?location=Whitby&amp;check_in=2020-05-18&amp;check_out=2020-05-21&amp;source_impression_id=p3_1588098317_3ZR4OmXOPF8LDdm7&amp;guests=1&amp;adults=1" property="og:url"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:title"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:description"/>
  <meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
  <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots"/>
  <meta content="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logos/trips-og-1280x630-9de9c338cc3fd9b5663fb80be0cbe8c2.jpg" property="og:image"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logos/trips-og-200x200-a3be4fbbb3b6c5e758804438dea35adc.jpg" rel="image_src"/>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" id="csrf-param-meta-tag" name="csrf-param"/>
  <meta content="null" id="csrf-token-meta-tag" name="csrf-token"/>
  <title>
   Holiday Lets, Homes, Experiences &amp; Places - Airbnb
  </title>
  <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="" id="english-canonical-url"/>
  <meta content="on" name="twitter:widgets:csp"/>
  <meta content="summary" name="twitter:card"/>
  <meta content="Holiday Lets, Homes, Experiences &amp; Places - Airbnb" name="twitter:title"/>
  <meta content="@airbnb" name="twitter:site"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" name="twitter:app:name:iphone"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" name="twitter:app:name:ipad"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" name="twitter:app:name:googleplay"/>
  <meta content="401626263" name="twitter:app:id:iphone"/>
  <meta content="401626263" name="twitter:app:id:ipad"/>
  <meta content="com.airbnb.android" name="twitter:app:id:googleplay"/>
  <meta content="https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/17394193" name="twitter:url"/>
  <link href="/opensearch.xml" rel="search" title="Airbnb" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/>
  <link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
  <meta content="yes" name="mobile-web-app-capable"/>
  <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" name="application-name"/>
  <meta content="Airbnb" name="apple-mobile-web-app-title"/>
  <meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color"/>
  <meta content="#ffffff" name="msapplication-navbutton-color"/>
  <meta content="black-translucent" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"/>
  <meta content="/?utm_source=homescreen" name="msapplication-starturl"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76-3b313d93b1b5823293524b9764352ac9.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76-3b313d93b1b5823293524b9764352ac9.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120-52b1adb4fe3a8f825fc4b143de12ea4b.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152-7b7c6444b63d8b6ebad9dae7169e5ed6.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180-bcbe0e3960cd084eb8eaf1353cf3c730.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/android-icon-192x192-c0465f9f0380893768972a31a614b670.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192"/>
  <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logotype_favicon-21cc8e6c6a2cca43f061d2dcabdf6e58.ico" rel="shortcut icon" sizes="76x76" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link color="#FF5A5F" href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/airbnb-0611901eac33ccfa5e93d793a2e21f09.svg" rel="mask-icon"/>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/runtime-b57b0e08.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/shims_post_modules-13ce83d5.js" type="module">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" nomodule="nomodule" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/shims_pre_modules-e891e725.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/moment/en-gb-83fb5bb3.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/core-guest-loop/phrases_manifest/en-GB/core-guest-spa/hyperloop/index-de105ecd10.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/moment-e464f4fa.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/react-53943884.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/aphrodite-effb7b96.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/d4ba-c3fe1044.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/d964-e35ee405.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/eece-9b1186c9.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/9026-0056b213.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/4894-c93ff27e.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/initializers-e188352f.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/53d5-e1ee27c8.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/9946-9c87f159.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/fc17-44f0a0fe.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/Corgi-App-5578808d.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/0e11-7806c3a4.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/bingo_pdp_route-prepare-d22facd5.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/71a3-4e5e722d.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/2cba-0b2d32e5.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/5a56-302bda2d.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/248a-079fbf22.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/3f20-43fca534.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/3fe7-7c5e5dbd.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/db73-649d484e.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/8a31-6d28d6eb.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/bingo_pdp_route-093e4aa4.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/2ce3-462fca54.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/13fb-41bb616c.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/f404-bcb05627.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/7c5a-023179b8.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/cb2d-db65c0cf.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/a295-ed403836.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/a8c2-81cd55c6.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/b7a5-dddbeaf4.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/f297-33c6a6e5.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/7c67-f40b955a.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/f8fa-fe0c81e4.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/fcb4-5d183261.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/698c-e577587b.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/e176-de3bd41d.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/fba3-29d6cafb.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/e99d-0e6236ae.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/bf4b-0f2b80d5.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/459b-ee73efd5.js">
  </script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" defer="" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/95b9-a39f5abd.js">
  </scr
```

Answer (score 1):

From this html snippet, it seems that you are not on the page that you want to be:

```
<title>
    Holiday Lets, Homes, Experiences &amp; Places - Airbnb
</title>
```

Since the title of the [url](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/17394193?location=Whitby&check_in=2020-05-18&check_out=2020-05-21&source_impression_id=p3_1588098317_3ZR4OmXOPF8LDdm7&guests=1&adults=1) that you want to **scrape** is actually this:

```
<title>
    Bumble Bee Studio Apartment - Flats for Rent in Whitby, England, United Kingdom
</title>
```

My guess is that you are being redirected to the main page of airbnb.

Comment: Thanks very much - that at least gives me something to look into!

Answer (score 1):

You need induce `WebDriverWait`() and  wait for `presence_of_element_located`() to load the element before you get the page source.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


Driver = webdriver.Firefox()
Driver.get("https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/17394193?location=Whitby&check_in=2020-05-18&check_out=2020-05-21&source_impression_id=p3_1588098317_3ZR4OmXOPF8LDdm7&guests=1&adults=1")
url = Driver.current_url
WebDriverWait(Driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table[role='presentation']")))
PageSourceURL = Driver.page_source
Soup = BeautifulSoup(PageSourceURL, features='html.parser')
PageHTML = Soup.prettify()
print(PageHTML)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the wait and things look a little better - i.e. its now pointing to the correct URL address, however the parsed data still does not contain any div elements etc. I'll see if I can add the update to the main question.  Thanks

Comment: Before driver.page_source put some time.sleep(10) hope you will get the html you are after.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It didn't change anything - but I'm not sure if my assumptions are correct (having very little experience in webscraping...).  So if I could really dumb this down to ensure my expectations are correct...
If on the web page I right click and then click 'inspect element' - I get a window with (in my example at least) loads of div class elements etc.  Its these I'm trying to find the parsed HTML.
Is my thinking correct?
Thanks very much for the help